# select all other elements inside div except the element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to start off by saying that this question will be tough to answer and tough to explain. I have a div with a list of buttons inside. When one of these buttons is clicked I want to make sure that all the other buttons are set to their default styles and the background of the button clicked to #4CC43C. I hope I explained it correctly. Also all the buttons are sent in by an ajax request. Other details have been omitted because it would be too hard to explain. Here is the code:

Php for getting the buttons:

```
   <?php
//code for connecting to database
    include("connect.html");

    $query = "select * from users";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connect);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo'
            <input type="button" class="searchResult" onclick="var oldValue = this.value; this.value=\'(selected) \' + oldValue; this.style.backgroundColor = \'#51CA3E\'; document.getElementById(\'hiddenUserFlag\').value = \''.$row['id'].'\';" value="'.$row['username'].'">
            ';
    }
    ?>
```

ajax request code:

```
function getUsers()
    {
         $( "#usersToSend" ).load( "php/getPrivateMessagingUsers.php" );
    }
```

Let me know if you don't understand and I will try to explain it better. Thank you.
Here is a screen shot of the application so you see what it's doing the code PROBLEM IS ON THE BOTTOM:
[image: picture of the application in action LOOK AT THE BOTTOM]

***The goal is too make the user know which other user they have selected. The rest is already complete.***

Comment: You need to use at least mysqli. You can use jQuery to do the button changing like `$(this).css('background', '#4CC43C')`. Use external JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit vague without some html for context and refined explanation of what can or can't be clicked.

At the highest level you can use the click event on the parent `<div>` and apply class ( or inline style) to the `target` of the click

```
$('div').click(function(evt){
     $(this).find('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');/* reset class from prior events */
     $(evt.target).addClass('clicked'); /* modify the target*/       
});
```

You can add extra conditional filters using methods like `$(evt.target).is('.buttonClass)` to help determine if class or style needs to be changed on the specific target

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nbcpuxzr/)**</kbd>

Comment: would help if you gave better defintiion to what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

you would probably achieve what you want using siblings() traversal function of jquery.

```
$('input.searchResult').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().each(function() {
    // do your stuff for each of the inputs not clicked.
  });
});
```

and if your inputs are nested in a structure of some sorts:

```
var $inputs = $('div#withThisId input');
$inputs.click(function(e) {
    $inputs.not(this).each(function() {/*do your stuff here*/});
});
```